# Rustlings Course Test4.rs Marcro Return Type Issue

Tags: types, rust, rust-macros

I am doing the Rustlings Rust-lang [course](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings/blob/master/exercises/test4.rs) and working on `exercises/test4.rs`

This is the only exercise in the course that does not come with a hint. So after working on it for a while, I'm reaching out to get that hint here!

```
macro_rules! my_macro {
    () => {
        println!("Hello!");
    };
    ($val:expr) => {
        println!("Hello {}", $val);
    }
}

fn main() {
    if my_macro!("world!") != "Hello world!" {
        panic!("Oh no! Wrong output!");
    }
}
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> test4.rs:20:31
   |
20 |     if my_macro!("world!") != "Hello world!" {
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected (), found reference
   |
   = note: expected type `()`
              found type `&'static str`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

The issue seems to be based on the fact that the default return type for a Rust macro is an empty tuple type (ie `expected type ()`), where as we compare it to a static string.

If the parameters of the exercise would allow me to alter the code in the main function, then the exercise seems like it would be a bit simpler. However, according to the instruction, the only thing to be done is to write a macro that causes the code to compile.

As I understand it, you cannot explicitly declare a return type for a macro. So I am at a loss as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the working answer I came up with:

```
fn function_rules(expr:&str)-> String{
    let a = "Hello";
    let b = expr;
    let result = [a, b].join(" ");
    return result.to_string();
}

macro_rules! my_macro {
    () => {
        println!("Hello!");
    };
    ($val:expr) => {
        //println!("Hello {}", $val);
        function_rules($val)
    }
}

fn main() {
    if my_macro!("world!") != "Hello world!" {
        panic!("Oh no! Wrong output!");
    }
}
```

I big part of solving this problem was dealing with String vs &str types, an excellent coverage of which can be found [here](https://hermanradtke.com/2015/05/03/string-vs-str-in-rust-functions.html).

The code compiles without modifying the main() function in any way, as per the instruction perameters. I think an even more elegant solution would have been to write a macro that returned the correct type without relying on an extra function. Assuming that's possible!

Answer (score 1):

I think the implementation could be much simpler:

```
macro_rules! my_macro {
    ($val:expr) => {
        format!("Hello {}", $val)
    }
}
```